# Java Regexp adding spaces to all characters after a part of string

Tags: java, regex, string, character, whitespace

I am trying to manipulate a string to a format of regexp

```
String months1 = "(?<month>(?i:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December))";
String monthsResult = months1.replaceAll("([^\\(\\?\\<month\\>\\(\\?i])([a-zA-Z])", "$0 ?");
```

I would like to have the result in format that after `(?<month>(?i:` would every character have a whitespace, but the code above shows:

```
(?<month>(?i:J ?an ?ua ?ry ?|F ?eb ?ru ?ar ?y|M ?ar ?ch ?|A ?pr ?il|M ?ay ?|J ?un ?e|J ?ul ?y|A ?ug ?us ?t|S ?ep ?tem ?be ?r|O ?ct ?obe ?r|N ?ove ?mbe ?r|D ?ec ?em ?be ?r))
```

Is there something to do with the grouping or my replaceAll function regexp is not exact?

Any help would be appreciated.

The expected result would be

```
"(?<month>(?i:J ?a ?n ?u ?a ?r ?y|F ?e ?b ?r ?u ?a ?r ?y|M ?a ?r ?c ?h|A ?p ?r ?i ?l|M ?a ?y|J ?u ?n ?e|J ?u ?l ?y|A ?u ?g ?u ?s ?t|S ?e ?p ?t ?e ?m ?b ?e ?r|O ?c ?t ?o ?b ?e ?r|N ?o ?v ?e ?m ?b ?e ?r|D ?e ?c ?e ?m ?b ?e ?r))
```

Comment: I think the `monthsLong` in the code is `months1` actually. Is that right?

Comment: If you add a string that shows the desired output it will make it easier for people to help you out. Your current description of the output you want is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
(?<=\(\?<month>\(\?i:.{0,16000})\w\B
```

Replaced with `$0 ?`.

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=\\(\\?<month>\\(\\?i:.{0,16000})\\w\\B", "$0 ?");
```

Comment: That gives out an Error: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 22

Comment: @user1463350, "not a word boundary".

Answer (score 0):

```
.replaceAll("(?<=(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]*)([a-z])", " ?$1");
```

Comment: @user1463350 I edited my answer, and it works as you expected.

Comment: Could you explain the lookbehind system?

Comment: @user1463350 Firstly, `(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]*` matches all small letters which after capital letter.Secondly, `(?<=(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]*)([a-z])` matches all single small letters which with capital letter behind them.

Comment: @user1463350 Put Simply, It matches the expression behind but not including them.